# Падают иксы на Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

После установки новой темы, что-то пошло не так и стали падать иксы. Удалил её и поставил тему по умолчанию, но иксы продолжают падать. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Покажите содержимое файла /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dlje1bviyxao9xo/log.zip?dl=0